# Verificar se input possui valor negativo

Tags: php

Tenho este exemplo que verifica se o input está recebendo apenas números, no caso ele verifica se possui apenas números positivos, se eu adicionar por exemplo um **0** ele já não funciona, tenho que adicionar dois zeros **00**, veja:

```
elseif (!is_numeric($adminAmount)) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'error'     => true,
        'message'   => 'A quantidade deve ser apenas números.'
    ));
}
```

Se for números continua se não ele retorna a mensagem de erro.

Existe alguma função nativa do PHP que verifica se o número é positivo ou negativo? por exemplo *+1* ou *-1* ?

Comment: Eu não entendi nada do que você disse aqui: `por exemplo um 0 ele já não funciona, tenho que adicionar dois zeros 00`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, chará! tipo se eu adiciono 1 (um) 0 no input ele me retorna a mensagem que ta no `json_encode` pra funcionar eu tenho que por dois(2) 00 no input.

Comment: Eu nem sei qual o comportamento de "funcionar" o qual você se refere, tá dificil de entender isso ai :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa de uma função só pra isto, para verificar se é positivo ou negativo basta usar `<` ou `>`, por exemplo:

```
$input = 1;

if ($input > -1) {
   echo 'Positivo';
} else if ($input < 0) {
   echo 'Negativo';
}
```

Ou `<=` e `>=`

```
$input = 1;

if ($input >= 0) {
   echo 'Positivo';
} else if ($input <= -1) {
   echo 'Negativo';
}
```

Agora sobre o comportamento de `00` funcionarem e um `0` não tá muito estranho, presumo que você tenha feito confusão, de qualquer forma você pode experimentar usar o `parseFloat`, porque talvez você nem esteja recebendo um numero válido, por exemplo:

```
$adminAmount = parseFloat($adminAmount);
```

Ainda sim o melhor é checar o formato que recebeu antes de tudo:

```
var_dump($adminAmount);
```

---

### Usando `filter_var` e `filter_input`

Você pode usar o [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) para limitar um `range`, por exemplo só aceitar numeros acima de `0`:

```
$adminAmount = filter_var($adminAmount, 
                      FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
                      array('options' => array('min_range' => 0)));
```

> Você controla o range em `array('min_range' => 0)`

Se os dados vierem por GET ou POST pode usar [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php):

```
$adminAmount = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'admin-amount',
                      FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
                      array('options' => array('min_range' => 0)));
```

> `'admin-amount'` é o nome do `<input>`

Se for POST:

```
$adminAmount = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'admin-amount',
                      FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
                      array('options' => array('min_range' => 0)));
```

Comment: Eu nem terminei de ver tudo, bati o olho nesse exemplo e arrumei, bom mas, tenho uma critica contra o PHP, se tem função pra verificar se é string ou numeros, deveria possuir uma função nativa pra verificar se é negativo pra facilitar nossa vida aoksokoaks. obg aguardando o tempo pra aceitar.

Comment: @Guilherme Uma função pra checar se é positivo ou negativo me parece bastante redundancia, ainda mais que o problema geral parece que foi alguma confusão de sua parte, no entanto vou adicionar uma outra sugestão.

Comment: Opa, toda sugestão pra mim é bem vinda. 20 anos de curso po! kkkkkk obg ]

Comment: acho que você confundiu parseFloat do javascript ele não existe no PHP. Pelo menos não que eu saiba e fui pesquisar e realmente não existe.

Comment: @Guilherme veja a edição da resposta, sobre o filter_var e filter_input

Comment: Opa, eu resolvi o problema no primeiro exemplo, mas vou ver o filter_input acho que fica mais dinâmico, e menos gabiarra.